# Не получается задать адрес отправителя при отправки почты

Tags: php, email, gmail

В общем, вся суть в том, что хостинг поддерживает только функцию отправки почты через php mail. При отправке сообщения указывается адрес отправителя. Почта приходит на gmail. Уже пробовал в headers указывать и дополнительным параметром -f. Ничего не работает, и адрес отправителя дублируется с адресом получателя. У меня уже закончились идеи как это можно реализовать.

Пробовал вот так

```
try {
$message = $_POST['message'];
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$to      = 'example@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Обращение пользователя '.$last_name.' '.$last_name;
$message = $_POST['message'];
$headers = 'From:'.$email. "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To:'.$email. "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
echo 'Сообщение успешно отправлено';
} catch (Exception $e) {
     echo 'Ошибка при отправке';
}
```

Comment: Покажите как пробовали, что получилось и как хотелось.

Comment: "Reply-To: example@gmail.com", т.е. вы обратный адрес ставите тот же, что и в $to. Обратный адрес тут должен быть тот же, что и from

Comment: from должен указывать на адрес сервера с которого идет отправка.

Comment: я по-разному указывал, сообщения вообще не приходят, если хотя бы где-то указывается обратный адрес

Comment: Уточните у хостера, может есть какие-то ограничения на отправку почты.